# Azure Accelerated Networking Enable Error PowerShell Status Code: 400

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

Azure Accelerated Networking Enable Error PowerShell Status Code: 400

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to **stop and deallocate** the VM first then enable the Accelerated Networking for the network interface. [Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli#enabling-accelerated-networking-on-a-running-vm) state this:

> A supported VM size without accelerated networking enabled can only
>   have the feature enabled when it is stopped and deallocated.

Also, check the [limitations and Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli#supported-operating-systems) for the Accelerated Networking.

[image]

Comment: yes, I was using right instance. During Creation of VM, there is a option to Enable Accelerated networking, but intentionally we have not enabled. Because we want to test how can we enable after deployment of a VM.

Comment: After you have deployed a VM, You just need to deallocate the VM before you want to enable Accelerated networking using the PowerShell commands above, then restart your VM. This works on my side.

Comment: Updated link to referenced document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-vm-accelerated-networking-cli?tabs=windows#manage-accelerated-networking-on-existing-vms